# Non-EU student wanting to start job right before submitting Masters thesis

Tags: germany, blue-card, students

I am a student in Munich and in the last stage of my thesis. I got a job (in IT) and my contract starts from June (this date has already been pushed from April and hence no further changes can happen). My company wants a work and residence permit for me to start working. Since I will be ending my thesis at that point, is it possible to apply for the EU blue card, given I won't have a Masters degree at hand and yet to submit my thesis?

Comment: The cited Duplicate has no answer.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica It is from the same user migrated from another site.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, It's the same question I posted there, but was told to post here

Comment: @yolo_ML That is no problem, but there should only be one.